# use VueRouter and Vue.js in Chrome Extension - Issues with path segments

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, routes, vue.js, vue-router

I developing a chrome extension with Vue.js. Works fine until I hit the part when I want to use routing.

On my local developing server where I have *localhost:8080/* this is not a problem when using following routing setup:

**main.js**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import App from "./App.vue";
import OptionComponent from "./OptionComponent.vue";

const routes = [
  { path: '/', component: App },
  { path: '/option', component: OptionComponent },
];

Vue.use(VueRouter); // This makes all the magic hapen and Vue recognizes the router-view and router-link

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes,
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>CM Server Descriptor</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
    <script src="libs/crypt.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/aja.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/JSLINQ.js"></script>
    <script src="js/build.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I deploy to my Chrome-Extension and start testing it there nothing happens.
I figured out that the chrome extension has some special path behaviours.

[image]

Here you can see that chrome has the path **/index.html** which is extra extra here.

What I then tried is the following:

```
const routes = [
  {path: '/' + chrome.runtime.id + '/index.html', component: App},
  {path: '/' + chrome.runtime.id + '/option', component: OptionComponent},
];
```

Did not helped. Changing to `/index` and `/` did not helped either...
Last try was trying to explicitely telling the protocol:

```
  {path: 'chrome-extension://' + chrome.runtime.id + '/', component: App},
```

No luck as well.
I assume that VueRouter only acts on **http://** protocol urls.

If anybody has an idea how to get around this I'd be very thankful!

Comment: I don't know vue.js but I know Chrome and it doesn't have a built-in web server so you need to use real html file path inside your extension relative to manifest.json folder like `path: '/index.html'`.

Comment: That sadly did not worked. I tried `{ path: 'index.html/', component: App },` as well without success

Comment: sorry I meant to type `/index.html` - was a typo. Yes the index.html is in the same root as the manifest. I added the index.html to the question

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue and I finally fixed it. It has been a year so not sure if it was fixed by chrome or Vue.

Anyway, I'll write down for anyone new to here:

Chrome pass URL based on folder structure and no implicit URL resolution. It means `/` won't redirect to `index.html`. So the solution is:

- **Either add a path for `index.html`:**

  ```
  { path: '/index.html', component: App },
  ```
- **Or add a path for your app and manual push to it when loaded.**

  ```
  //router.js
  { path: '/app', component: App },
  ```

File `App.vue`

```
created(){
    this.$router.push('app');
}
```

And remember the routing path needs to exactly match the relative path in your chrome extension root. So if you put `index.html` in extension root, your Vue `baseUrl` must be `/`

Answer (score 6):

Chrome is pointing at your popup.html file you´ve registered in the mainfest, which then will not be found by your router.

**Setting the base url to the popup.html (depending on it´s location relative to the mainfest.json) solves it**

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  base: '/popup/popup.html',
  mode: 'history',
  routes,
});
```

Comment: This was exactly it.  Looking in the Dist folder in my project, its not nested within a popup dir.  So I changed base to `/popup.html`

Comment: Thank you very much it was exactly the answer i needed :D

Answer (score 0):

Just to build on Marian's answer, the latest version of VueRouter has moved the base option to the createWebHistory function. So it would look something like this -

```
const routes = /** your route definitions **/[]
createRouter({ history: createWebHistory('popup.html'), routes })
```

Answer (score -2):

Chrome extensions have to comply with CSP (Content Security Policy) so you can't use Vue 2 because it's based on eval().

You need to use the CSP version of Vue and Vue-router version 1.0 to go with:

**Vue 1.0-csp**

https://github.com/vuejs/vue/tree/1.0-csp

**Vue-router 1.0**

https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/tree/1.0

Comment: This answer is irrelevant and completely wrong on top of that. -1 https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#CSP-environments

Comment: Vue 2 is also CSP compliant, as the comment above me states.