# Vue router not load components in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-chrome-extension, vuejs2

I'm creating a chrome extension that will use vue and vue router. 
I'm able to make vue working using the `sandbox` inside manifest.json and this will bypass the CSP that is restrictive for the chrome extensions. I have a problem with vue-router,I'm not able to display the views that I've created using `Vue.component` . [I found this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44530237/use-vuerouter-and-vue-js-in-chrome-extension-issues-with-path-segments) but didn't solved my issue. Here is the code, anyone can help me?

```
const welcomeScreen = Vue.component({
  template: '#welcome-screen'
});

const newChatroom = Vue.component({
  template: '#create-chat'
});

const accessChatroom = Vue.component({
  template: '#access-chat'
});

const chatroom = Vue.component({
  template: '#chat-board'
});

const routes = [
  { path: '/', component: welcomeScreen },
  { path: '/create-room', component: newChatroom },
  { path: '/access-room/:id', component: accessChatroom },
  { path: '/chatroom/:id', component: chatroom }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  base: '/popup.html',
  mode: 'history',
  routes,
})

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    mounted() {
        console.log('Vue started');
    },
    methods: {
      initChat(){
       // code...
      },
      channelSetup(){
        // code...
      }
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

The problem still remain also if I use the default vue router hash navigation mode. Another thing is that I'm not using webpack, so I need to use sandbox mode for the extension otherwise I have a problem with CSP.

This is what I get instead on the welcomeScreen component, a blank frame
[image]

Comment: Vue works in an extension without the need for sandboxing or CSP hacks, there are many extensions around which you can inspect if you want a working example. As for routing, the files in an extension are not served by a server so try using the router in URL hash mode which is the default mode.

Comment: Can you provide an example for the router? For the CSP, if I deactivate the sandbox for my `popup.html`, it will give me this error `[Vue warn]: It seems you are using the standalone build of Vue.js in an environment with Content Security Policy that prohibits unsafe-eval. The template compiler cannot work in this environment. Consider relaxing the policy to allow unsafe-eval or pre-compiling your templates into render functions.`

Comment: you were likely experiencing this problem https://stackoverflow.com/q/44530237/812919 , I currently am, but not for long 