# Problems with rendering Vue Router 4 + Vue 3 (migration build)

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router, webpack-4

#### Context

I'm migrating my application from vue 2 to vue 3, and I'm using the compatibility version ([migration build](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/migration-build.html)).
My application is a WebExtension (browser extension).

##### Application flow

- Manifest.json calls the function (make-spa.js) to include a div.
- Make-spa.js creates a div and inserts a shadowRoot after calling the function (app.js)
- App.js is where Vue 3 is mounted together with the Router

#### Problem

The application renders but the router-view does not work. however if you use a console.log( useRouter().path) it shows the console.

#### What I've already tried

- Follow the migration guide documentation
- Tried using vue 3 compatibility mode only for the router
- Tried to use all components in vue 3
- Updated node version to 16
- I tried to simplify the application to use only two components without any requirements that could get in the way.
- Tried changing router history modes
- Tried to import router-view from vue-router directly in component
- Tried to render without shadow root

#### Code to analyze the problem:

```
"devDependencies": {
...,
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.1.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.4.4",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
    "sass": "^1.62.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.4.1",
    "vue-loader": "^16.0.0",
    "webpack": "^4.44.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
    "webpack-extension-reloader": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@kyvg/vue3-notification": "^2.9.1",
    "@vue/compat": "^3.1.0",
    "vue": "^3.1.0",
    "vue-custom-element": "^3.2.14",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.0"
  }
```

```js
// app.js
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import Teste from './Teste.vue';
import { createRouter, createMemoryHistory } from 'vue-router';
import TesteStart from './TesteStart.vue';


let router = createRouter({
  history: createMemoryHistory(),
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: TesteStart,
    }
  ]
});

let element = document.getElementById('cpn-wrapper')?.shadowRoot.getElementById('cuponomia');

const app = createApp(Teste);
app.use(router);
app.mount(element);
```

Teste.vue

```js
<template>
  <div>
    Teste
    <br />
    <router-view></router-view>
    <br />
    Teste
  </div>
</template>
<script setup></script>
<style></style>
```

TesteStart.vue

```js
<template>
  <div>Teste Start</div>
</template>
<script setup>
</script>
```

Router view working and my application

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44530237/use-vuerouter-and-vue-js-in-chrome-extension-issues-with-path-segments